# PHP Chat Box : How to Update Automatically

Tags: php, sql, database, chat

Recently, I've made a chat box using PHP. There's no problem, but it is not very convenient as I need to manually refresh the page to check for the new message.

I'm trying to find a way so that the chat box will automatically check for new message and it will show new message.

However, what can I do? Could I

1. Use `<iframe>` for the chat box and find a way to refresh the iframe only;
2. Use javascript to check the SQL Database (it is not safe, discussed in another question, but is possible)
3. Use ajax - I don't know anything about it, so I cannot do so.

Which of the above way is the most suitable one (and if possible, the easiest one)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ajax is going to be your best option, but believe me, it's not so bad.

I hate to turn this into a tutorial, but here's a general outline.

1. Create a php file that gets the messages, if any, and prints them somehow. Maybe some list items? `echo "<li>$message</li>"`
2. Create a jquery interval that checks for messages every set seconds.
3. Have your interval call a function with code like this:

   ```
   $.get( "get_messages.php", function( data ) { //data contains the file's output

    $( "#messages-box" ).append( data );//insert the new messages into a div in your html

   });
   ```

That's really all there is to it!

Comment: I agree with you, and however I'm gonna try the iframe and javascript soution. I'll try it and well, I forgot to tell you that it is connected with a SQL Database so I can't use your method.

Comment: @Jamie Why would connecting to a database be a problem? That can be done in get_messages.php just fine.

Comment: Can I use a plain javascript interval instead? I cannot use jQuery. I don't know much about it.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/vYwzn4JD Here is the code of my Chat Box. I need some help. What should I do with this code?

Comment: Hmmm... I would seriously recommend learning Jquery. The language is meant to make Javascript MUCH less of a headache. It's amazingly faster and easier to write. All an interval in Jquery and Javascript is, is a function calling itself with a set delay. However, yes, you can use vanilla javascript for intervals and ajax requests. But it's going to be really confusing. I doubt it will take you more than half an hour to get used to JQuery.

Comment: Please remove your pastebin entry and change your mysql password. You should never post mysql connection credentials publicly.

Comment: Oh, I see. However, jQuery make me headache.

Comment: I cannot remove the pastebin entry. I can only change mysql password. However, nobody can check my sql db because it has restricted access against not-correct-ip website.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax is just a component of javascript.  To create a chat box with php and javascript, the simplest solution is using setInterval function to refresh the chatbox